# What's the way to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 for CFFI that takes the least harddrive space?

Tags: python, c++, python-cffi, visual-c++

I want to write Python software that uses `CFFI`. `CFFI` itself throws the error:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

There are multiple downloads on that page. I fancy not installing gigabyte worth of data from the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. 
What's the minimum that I have install for `CFFI` to work?

Comment: I don't know what the page looks like for you, but I see two download links, and the first one is 3.1 MB. Unless it's one of those installers that pulls in a bunch more data over the internet once you launch it, there doesn't seem to be anything to worry about regarding size.

Comment: @user2357112 : When trying to install the first one it says "Setup requires 4 GB across all devices".

Comment: Go for Visual Stdio 2017, you can selectively install only the package unlike earlier versions. The latest IDE also load programs much faster.

Comment: @seccpur: that sounds perfect. If you are confident – or know from experience – it should work, post it as an answer!

Comment: @seccpur : Which of those packages have to be installed for CFFI?

Comment: @Christian: It has separate Python development and VC++ development options. In VC++ install option you can find cross compiler option, you can go there. Frankly, I am more of VC++ and Android developer.